# How to rotate a plane over z-axis and y-axis in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, rotation, matlab-figure, plane

Given a point `(x0,y0,z0)` on 3d plane, first I want to plot a plane `x=x0` that passes through the given point `(x0,y0,z0)`, and then rotate that plane `alpha` degree on y-axis and `beta` degree on z-axis. The final plane should also pass through the point point `(x0,y0,z0)`.

Here is an example when the given point was `(4,5,6)`, `alpha=30` and `beta=45`, and I manage to rotate 30 degree on y-axis only:

```
x0=4;
y0=5;
z0=6;
alpha=30;
beta=45;
plot3(x0,y0,z0,'r*')
hold on
[Y1, Z1] = meshgrid(linspace(-10,10), linspace(0,10));
X1 = x0*ones(size(Y1));
surf(X1,Y1,Z1)
hold on
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z');
X2 = (Z1)*tand(alpha)-z0*ones(size(Z1))*tand(alpha)+X1;
surf(X2,Y1,Z1)
```

Can you please help me to simultaneously rotate original plane `x=x0` over y-axis and z-axis, so that the final plane passes through `(x0,y0,z0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial point are:

```
p1 = [x0,y0,z0]
```

Your initial plane equation is:

```
F = a*x + b*y + c*z + d == 0 % with a=1, b=0, c=0 and d=-x0
F = x == x0
```

Based on this equation you can generate two more point `p2` and `p3`.

Apply two [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) `Ry` and `Rz` to your points:

```
[p1',p2',p3'] = [p1,p2,p3]*Ry*Rz
```

Then compute your new plane equation `F' = a*x + b*y + c*z + d == 0` that fit `[p1',p2',p3']` (with a cross product) and finally adjust the parameter `d` so that `F'(p1) = 0`. Let's call that new equation `F''`. You have your final plane equation and you can plot your surface.

To generate the plane your can again use `meshgrid` and isolate the `z` parameter of you `F''` function: `z = -(a*x +b*y + d)/c`